# Observe value changes when submit button pressed in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, typescript2.0

I have an edit form as below which contains data in the input fields.

```
<ng-form #infoForm="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div>
                <label for="firstName">First Name :</label>
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="firstName"
                       name="firstName"
                       [(ngModel)]="in.firstName">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lastName">Last Name :</label>
                <input type="text"
                       autocomplete="on"
                       class="form-control"
                       id="lastName"
                       name="lastName"
                       [(ngModel)]="in.lastName">
            </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateInfo(infoForm.value)">Update
                </button>
    </ng-form>
```

And I have the function in the component as below:

```
updateInfo(info: any) {
        console.log(info);
}
```

This form return all the values (to the console) in the form when the Update button clicked, but I want to submit only the edited values instead of whole form. How could I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can pass the form instead of its value to 'updateInfo' function and process it there. If user change the control value its state becomes 'dirty' from 'touched/pristine' and we can filter controls based on that.

Change in html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateInfo(infoForm)">Update
        </button>
```

Change in *.ts file:

```
updateInfo(info: NgForm) {
    const changedValues = Object.keys(info.controls)
      .filter(key => info.controls[key].dirty === true)
      .map(key => {
        return { control: key, value: info.controls[key].value }
      });
    console.log(changedValues);
  }
```

Comment: How could I build it in an array? e.g: {firstName: "john", lastName: "sam"}

Comment: Just update the return object inside map as you need.